# GPS third party (free or pay for license) component

Tags: gps, serial-port, gis

i am looking for a third party software component (in SDK or DLL) to build in a existing commercial GIS software.

One of the features i am looking for is converting the gps location (bluetooth GPS receiver) to X,Y values based on the GPS map projection.

I looked at different products but still can not find a dll or sdk which can at least:

detect a existing bluetooth GPS receiver for example (Global-Sat BT-368) and 
read (listening) to the right COM serial port e.g. COM10,  BaudRate:4800
and return the current GPS location in X,Y values based on the GPS map projection.

If someone knows a product that can do this or how to code this in .NET i will be very thankful

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to break your request up into smaller parts here if you want to get some useful feedback. You have at least three separate requirements here that will probably be best solved with different products.

- Signal acquisition (any reason you couldn't use System.IO.Ports?)
- Conversion of lat/lon into X,Y for a given map projection (this is basic trigonometry. Google lat/lon to xy)
- Display results on map (many many open source applications for this. [MapWindow](http://www.mapwindow.org/) springs to mind but take your pick)

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks for your reply. 

Here are my answers to your questions:
1: IO.Ports listening its a possibility. First it depends if we can find a ready to use dll thats have this build like => 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13577/GPS-Deriving-British-Ordnance-Survey-Grid-Referenc
or http://gps3.codeplex.com/
Its not decided yet. 

2: On this one i found a lot of information, thanks for the hint. But i am still working on it. I think i will put a new thread for this one

3: Thanks for the link of MapWindow. 

Thx, 
gr Curley